# Java - unexpected result when rounding a double/float to 2 decimals

Tags: java, math, double, decimal

I encounter a problem when round a double to 2 decimals. I know this questions have been asked in many places. But my question is slightly different and I cannot find it in other places.

So far as I know, there are 2 ways to do this.

1. `Math.round(double*100.0)/100.0`
2. `DecimalFormat(“###.##”)`

I am trying to use the first way: a custom way to round double. 
When the second decimal is 0, the result will only print the first decimal and ignore the second one.

For example,

1. `Math.round(1.23333*100.0)/100.0` The result is 1.23. This works good.
2. `Math.round(3.90*100.0)/100.0.` The result is 3.9. Problem occurs. I want to show 3.90 instead of 3.9
3. `Math.round(3*100.0)/100.0`. The result is 4.0. I want 4.00 instead of 4.0

So, my question is that how I can have a double value with 2 decimals no matter if the last decimal is 0 or not. **I know I can use the second way- `DecimalFormat(“###.##”)` to achieve what I want! But is it possible to do it by using the first way?**

Edit: Thanks for the answers. It looks like it is NOT possible to use the round() method to achieve it. However, some people suggest to use the combination of 2 ways to achieve it. But I think using only `DecimalFormat(“###.##”)` can get what I want. Can anyone confirm it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the following?

```
DecimalFormat(“###.00”)
```

If not mistaken, trailing zeros are left blank when using the #-sign.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using String.format("%1$.2f",x). It rounds the value to the specified precision (2 digits in our example) and leaves the trailing zeros on the right.

```
System.out.println(String.format("%1$.2f",3.121)) gives 3.12
System.out.println(String.format("%1$.2f",3.129)) gives 3.13
System.out.println(String.format("%1$.2f",3.12))  gives 3.12
System.out.println(String.format("%1$.2f",3.10))  gives 3.10
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to use a combination of both to achieve your needs.
The rounding to obtain a number with two decimals, and the `DecimalFormat` to display it with two decimals.

Answer (score 0):

You should be formatting your result with `DecimalFormat`

```
DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
System.out.println(Math.round(3.90*100.0)/100.0); // 3.9
System.out.println(format.format(Math.round(3.90*100.0)/100.0)); // after using format 3.90
System.out.println(format.format(Math.round(3*100.0)/100.0));
```

And the output is

```
3.9
3.90
3.00
```

Comment: I think using only DecimalFormat without Math.round can also get what I want. I was wondering if I can only use Math.round() to do it. I think the answer is "no" now.